# How to extract the .img files using c#

Tags: c#, .net-core

Do we have any methods or API  available to extract the the contents of .img files using C#.

FYI, This .img file is an ISO file, which contains lot many folders and files inside it

Comment: I don't think there's any built-in functionality for ISO files in .NET or .NET Core.

Comment: is a .img or a .iso? Idf you rename to .rar can you extract it with an unzip utility? There's your answer.

Comment: Have tried by renaming the file, but got an exception "first magic byte doesn't match". That's a good try though. @Nick.McDermaid

Comment: You need to work what actual type of file you are opening, it would seem it isn't an ISO file. Where did the file come from? what created it?